# What would O(n) + o(nlogn) be?

Tags: performance, algorithm

What would o(nlogn) + O(n) be ?

My guess is O(nlogn) ?

f1(n) = o(nlogn) means for each constant c, there is an n0 such that 0 <= f1(n) < cnlogn .

And f2(n) = O(n) means there exists some constant c1, such that for n > n1, 0 <= f2(n) <= c1n .

so , all I can get from this is that, there is some constant c1, such that for n > max(n0,n1), 0 <= f1(n) + f2(n) <= c1(nlogn) .

Comment: @CalebB: "returns"? I think you don't understand the question at all.

Comment: fix the Q. you don't use n0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at asymptotical limits of those functions and their sum.

First, upper limit:

```
F1 = o(n*log(n)), F2 = O(n) = o(n*log(n)), so
F1 + F2 = o (n* log(n))
```

Second, lower limit: we know F2 is O(N), but F1 can be zero for all we know, or anywhere between zero and n * log(n). So all we can say for sure is that F1+F2 is not o(N).

I will let you put all that in terms of 'for each constant C there exists an index n' yourself.

EDIT: Douglas pointed out that big-Oh and little-Oh are upper bounds only, and strictly speaking, you can't say anything about lower bounds at all. This is absolutely correct.

However, in programming most of the time what we actually care about are worst-case scenarios, and nobody says that sqrt(n) = O(n) – which would technically be correct. So yes, we can talk about lower bounds, in a sense, if we mean worst-case.

Comment: Can you please explain O(n) = o(n*log(n)) . From O(n) we know there exists some constant c , such that f(n) < cn . From this how can we derive the result of making it work for all constants c , for nlogn.

Comment: @Shekhar , I don't think you solved it for small-oh. Note, nlogn is in small-oh notation and n is in big-oh.

Comment: @ameyask86 This statement is not equality, of course. It means that if f=O(n), then f=o(n*log(n)). This is immediately obvious once you do this kind of thing for some time, but if it isn't, it's easy to prove using "c and n".  Sorry, I will leave that as exercise, try to prove it yourself :)

Comment: @letitbee , got it, so suppose we find a c such that 0<= f(n) <= cn for some n > N . This gives us 0<= f(n) < c n logn for n > N. But what if we have a constant c1 <c . Can the bound for  nlogn be made to work ? I guess , we pick a large enough N so that log N > c/c1 . So that f(n) < c n gives us f(n) < c1 n log N. Thanks. I hope this is the approach.

Comment: I thank you Shekhar for your response, but being the OP , I think I am in a better position to judge which answer explained it better to me . Thanks.

Comment: @ameyask86, more or less, yes, you got it.

Comment: You can't "say for sure" that F1+F2 is not o(N). It is a common mistake to think that O(N) means Theta(N). It does not. You do not know that a function that is only stated to be O(N) is not also O(Sqrt(N)) or O(1).

Comment: @DouglasZare, sure, both functions can be constant for all we know. This is all worst case, of course.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  My main concern was that I had a linear time operation and an operation which uses o(n*logn) .Since it is shown that combined operation would take up o(n*logn) time , my purpose is achieved.

Comment: Yes, both functions can be constants, so your statement that we know the sum is not o(n) is wrong. Please fix it.

Comment: @DouglasZare Once again: worst case. Worst case is what matters.

Comment: Wait, this is not that you think the mistake is too small to bother fixing, you really think your statement that F1+F2 can't be o(N) is correct, even though you admit F1 and F2 could be constants, and constant+constant is a constant, and constants are o(N)? You could argue that you want the + operator to mean something more between classes, but saying that F1+F2 can't be o(N) is just flat wrong.

Comment: There is a fine line between accuracy and nitpicking, @Douglas. This is really not worth getting worked up about. I added an edit, hope you find it satisfiable.

Comment: I find your edit rude. Don't blame me or overly sensitive mathematicians that your objective statement that f1+f2 could not be o(N) is wrong. Just fix it. It's not what "worst case" means.

Comment: By the way, there are plenty of contexts in which people indeed say things like "this is at most sqrt(n), so it's O(n) and disappear into this O(n) term..." It's a common mistake to say that O(n) can't be used for smaller functions. It's a bound. Saying that someone is under 10 feet tall doesn't mean he or she is tall.

Comment: Fixed the edit. You realize I understand your point, right? That's why I added an edit stating that you are correct. I'm sorry, I'm done with this argument now, there isn't anything useful anymore to emerge from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76289/discussion-between-letitbee-and-douglas-zare).

Answer (score 4):

If f is o(n log n) and g is O(n), then g is also o(n log n) so **f+g is o(n log n)**.

You do not get a positive lower bound. You do not get to say f+g can't be o(n) or even o(1). The function 0 is both O(n) and o(n log n). So is sqrt(n).

Big-O and little-o notations are asymptotic upper bounds for the magnitude. They are not lower bounds. Big-Omega and little-omega are lower bounds. Theta means you have both an upper bound and a lower bound of the same form. **When you add together two upper bounds, you get an upper bound.** You do not get a positive lower bound. In particular, you can't claim that the sum is not o(n).

Comment: I really missed the whole essence in my answer. And the reason for so I was in a hurry to frame answers. Whatever you mentioned is absolutely correct and the same matches with what I wanted to deliver here. But,I failed to do so. Thanks for pointing out the errors. I won't hastily give answers in the future without deep judgement. Thanks and good luck...